# ASP.NET: GridView pageEventValidation problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the following code:

EnquiryList.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EnquiryList.ascx.cs" Inherits="includes_EnquiryList"%>
<div class="EnquiryForm" runat="server">

    <asp:GridView ID="gridMain" 
        runat="server" 
        PageSize="20"
        Width="390"
        GridLines="None" 
        CssClass="gridview" 
        AllowPaging="True"
        AllowSorting="True" 
        CellPadding="0" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        OnPageIndexChanging="gridMain_PageIndexChanging"
        OnRowCommand="gridMain_RowCommand"
        DataSourceID="ldsGridMain">

        <Columns>

             <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <%# Eval("Id") %>
                    <asp:Button Text="Bekräfta" ID="apa" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Buy" class="enquiryBtn"/>

                </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsGridMain" runat="server" OnSelecting="ldsGridMain_Selecting" OnSelected="ldsGridMain_Selected"/>

</div>
```

EnquiryList.ascx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;
using Offerta.Presentation;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public partial class includes_EnquiryList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    protected Boolean IsAuthenticatedSupplier { get; set; }

    protected Boolean ShowSimilarEnquiriesLink { get; set; }

    protected int totalRows = 0;

    protected LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs selectArgs;

    protected Supplier supplier;

    protected IQueryable<Enquiry> enquiries;

    protected string errorMessage;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsAuthenticatedSupplier = false;
        Auth auth = new Auth();
        if (auth.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            IsAuthenticatedSupplier = auth.ClientTypeId == ClientMethods.CLIENT_TYPE_SUPPLIER;
            if (IsAuthenticatedSupplier)
            {
                supplier = (Supplier)auth.Client;
            }
        }
    }


    public void Bind(IQueryable<Enquiry> enquiries)
    {
        this.enquiries = enquiries;
        gridMain.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ldsGridMain_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        selectArgs = e;
        e.Result = (new EnquiryListController()).List(enquiries, supplier);
    }

    protected void ldsGridMain_Selected(object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        totalRows = selectArgs.Arguments.TotalRowCount;
    }

    protected void gridMain_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gridMain.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gridMain.DataBind();
    }

    protected void gridMain_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
    //never gets here?
    switch (e.CommandName.ToString())
        {
            case "Buy":
                PurchaseEnquiry(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void PurchaseEnquiry(string enquiryId)
    {
        try
        {
            Enquiry enquiry = EnquiryMethods.Get(new Guid(enquiryId));
            Order order = OrderMethods.Purchase(supplier, enquiry);
            Response.Redirect((new UrlFactory()).GetSupplierEnquiryMessageUrl(order.Id.ToString()), true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorMessage = e.Message;        
        }
    }

}
```

In SupplierInbox.aspx.cs (SupplierInbox.aspx basically only contains a EnquiryList and html)

```
using System;

public partial class SupplierInbox : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new Auth()).RequireClientOfType(ClientMethods.CLIENT_TYPE_SUPPLIER);
        ucEnquiryList.Bind(EnquiryMethods.BuildQuery(new EnquiryQuery()));
    }

}
```

When pressing the Button in the GridView I keep getting

> Invalid postback or callback argument.
>   Event validation is enabled using
>   
>   in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a
>   page.  For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate
>   from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data
>   is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation.

If I disable EventValidation, nothing happens when I press the button, i.e. gridMain_RowCommand is never called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding  if(!IsPostBack) ucEnquiryList.Bind(EnquiryMethods.BuildQuery(new EnquiryQuery()));

Comment: Thanks. I was having the same problem and that fixed it for me as well

Comment: did you leave EventValidation enabled in the fix as well?